# Multiple Entries in a Tradingview Strategy

Tags: pine-script

EDIT////Ok, I see that this is all related to the calculate on every tick thing. It won't actually backtest something every 10 seconds accurately. The most you can accurate test inside tradingview on a 5 minute candle, is one batch of orders every 5 minutes. So maybe limit entries as deeper bids would give a better average entry.

Basically this script makes an initial entry when the condition to long occurs and then is suppose to place a new bid every 10 seconds until the maximum allowable contracts limitation kicks in (actually it's suppose to be USD value but I can't use that, need to make it work for ethereum)

I think that defining the variable flipstamp with the time is what is breaking it. I need to record the UTC time in unix format at the time the reversal happens in order for the loop to work, which uses the var counter, i.e, it is suppose to start at the reversal time and add increments of 10 seconds as a condition so that only one bid is placed every 10 seconds. (or however many seconds, this is just an example)
When you plot this the additional entries don't work, and don't go through. Ideas?

```
//@version=4

strategy(title="Example: maximum position size", overlay=false, pyramiding=390, default_qty_type=strategy.fixed, default_qty_value=100, precision=0)

// Calculate the moving averages
quickMA = ema(close, 25)
slowMA = ema(close, 200)

// Trade at most 1,000 shares long or short
strategy.risk.max_position_size(contracts=390)

// Plot position size and its maximum
plot(series=strategy.position_size, style=plot.style_areabr, color=strategy.position_size > 0 ? color.green : color.red)

hline(price=1000, color=color.orange, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(price=-1000, color=color.orange, linestyle=hline.style_solid)

// Determine trading conditions
GoLong = crossover(quickMA, slowMA)
GoShort = crossunder(quickMA, slowMA)

// Submit initial entry orders
if GoLong
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true)

if GoShort
    strategy.entry(id="ES", long=false)

flipstamp = 0

if GoLong or GoShort //and barssince(GoLong) % 1 == 0 or barssince(GoShort) % 1 == 0
    flipstamp := time
var int baseincrement_id=0
var int baseunit_increment_total = flipstamp 
timeDifference = (time - time[1]) / 1000
timebaseunit = timeDifference / 10

if timenow > baseunit_increment_total 
    baseunit_increment_total :=  baseunit_increment_total + timebaseunit
    baseincrement_id := baseincrement_id + 1

// Submit entry orders
if (GoLong)
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true, qty=.195)

if (GoShort)
    strategy.entry(id="ES", long=false, qty=.195)

if timenow > baseunit_increment_total and strategy.position_size > 0 and barssince(GoLong)<barssince(GoShort)
    strategy.entry(id="OPartLong", long=true, qty=.0025, when=GoLong)
    
if timenow > baseunit_increment_total and strategy.position_size < 0 and barssince(GoLong)>barssince(GoShort)
    strategy.entry(id="OPartShort", long=false, qty=.0025, when=GoShort)
```

Comment: I tried going back to use barssince and valuewhen, but basically I can get the bar index value for the bar that the long short signal occurance, but I can't pass it as a variable into time[variable], I get a "can't reference series chart error" and max bars back doesn't fix it.